# Issue Hang Detox Test after setting Jest with detox environnement

Tags: jestjs, react-native, detox

this is what I get as error on console having no idea how to solve it

```
 detox test -c Adebug --loglevel verbose   
detox[13529] INFO:  [test.js] DETOX_CONFIGURATION="Adebug" DETOX_FORCE_ADB_INSTALL=false DETOX_LOGLEVEL="verbose" DETOX_READ_ONLY_EMU=false DETOX_REPORT_SPECS=true DETOX_START_TIMESTAMP=1616519506213 DETOX_USE_CUSTOM_LOGGER=true jest --config e2e/config.json --testNamePattern '^((?!:ios:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 e2e
detox[13530] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:56236...
detox[13530] DEBUG: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_OPEN] opened web socket to: ws://localhost:56236
detox[13530] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=tester, sessionId=3529d3cf-9fa0-d471-2c8e-738e1be0eb36
detox[13530] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=tester, sessionId=3529d3cf-9fa0-d471-2c8e-738e1be0eb36
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #0] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator" -list-avds --verbose
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #1] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator" -version 
detox[13530] DEBUG: [EmulatorVersionResolver.js/EMU_BIN_VERSION_DETECT] Detected emulator binary version { major: 30, minor: 4, patch: 5, toString: [Function: toString] }
detox[13530] DEBUG: [EmulatorDeviceAllocation.js/ALLOCATE_DEVICE] Trying to allocate a device based on "Pixel_3"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #2] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb"  devices
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #2] List of devices attached
emulator-16296  device


detox[13530] DEBUG: [FreeDeviceFinder.js/DEVICE_LOOKUP] Found a matching & free device emulator-16296
detox[13530] DEBUG: [EmulatorDeviceAllocation.js/ALLOCATE_DEVICE] Settled on emulator-16296
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #3] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "getprop dev.bootcomplete"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #4] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #5] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "settings put global animator_duration_scale 0"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #6] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "settings put global window_animation_scale 0"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #7] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "settings put global transition_animation_scale 0"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #8] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "dumpsys power | grep \"^[ ]*m[UW].*=\""
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #9] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/aapt" dump badging "/Users/medsalahbdioui/reactProjects/dailyPso/android/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug/app-dev-debug.apk" | grep -e "package: name="
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #10] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "am force-stop fr.infostrates.dailypsodev"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #11] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "pm list packages fr.infostrates.dailypsodev"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #12] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 uninstall fr.infostrates.dailypsodev
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #13] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "pm list packages fr.infostrates.dailypsodev.test"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #14] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 uninstall fr.infostrates.dailypsodev.test
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #15] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "rm -fr /data/local/tmp/detox"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #16] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "mkdir -p /data/local/tmp/detox"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #17] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 push "/Users/medsalahbdioui/reactProjects/dailyPso/android/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug/app-dev-debug.apk" "/data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #18] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #19] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 push "/Users/medsalahbdioui/reactProjects/dailyPso/android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/dev/debug/app-dev-debug-androidTest.apk" "/data/local/tmp/detox/Test.apk"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #20] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Test.apk"
detox[13530] INFO:  Example is assigned to emulator-16296 (Pixel_3)
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #21] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "am force-stop fr.infostrates.dailypsodev"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #22] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "date +\"%m-%d %T.000\""
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #23] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 reverse tcp:56236 tcp:56236
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #24] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "pm list instrumentation"
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #25] [pid=13561] /Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-16296 shell am instrument -w -r -e detoxServer ws://localhost:56236 -e detoxSessionId 3529d3cf-9fa0-d471-2c8e-738e1be0eb36 -e debug false fr.infostrates.dailypsodev.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #26] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "ps | grep \"fr\.infostrates\.dailypsodev$\""
detox[13530] ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #26] ""/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "ps | grep \"fr\.infostrates\.dailypsodev$\""" failed with error = ChildProcessError: Command failed: "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "ps | grep \"fr\.infostrates\.dailypsodev$\""
 `"/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "ps | grep \"fr\.infostrates\.dailypsodev$\""` (exited with error code 1) (code=1), stdout and stderr:

detox[13530] ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #26] 
detox[13530] ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #26] 
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #27] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 shell "ps | grep \"fr\.infostrates\.dailypsodev$\""
detox[13530] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=app not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=3529d3cf-9fa0-d471-2c8e-738e1be0eb36)
detox[13530] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=app not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=3529d3cf-9fa0-d471-2c8e-738e1be0eb36)
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/KILL] sending SIGINT to [pid = 13561]: /Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-16296 shell am instrument -w -r -e detoxServer ws://localhost:56236 -e detoxSessionId 3529d3cf-9fa0-d471-2c8e-738e1be0eb36 -e debug false fr.infostrates.dailypsodev.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
detox[13530] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #28] "/Users/medsalahbdioui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-16296 reverse --remove tcp:56236
detox[13530] INFO:  Example: should have welcome screen
detox[13530] INFO:  Example: should have welcome screen [FAIL]

detox[13530] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = -1000) isReady: {}

Unresponded network requests might result in timeout errors in Detox tests.

detox[13530] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=tester, sessionId=3529d3cf-9fa0-d471-2c8e-738e1be0eb36
detox[13530] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/WS_CLOSE] Detox server connections terminated gracefully
 FAIL  e2e/firstTest.e2e.js (18.393 s)
  Example
    ✕ should have welcome screen (1 ms)

  ● Example › should have welcome screen

    DetoxRuntimeError: Failed to run application on the device

    HINT: Most likely, your tests have timed out and called detox.cleanup() while it was waiting for "ready" message (over WebSocket) from the instrumentation process.

      at MonitoredInstrumentation._getInstrumentationCrashError (../node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/android/tools/MonitoredInstrumentation.js:68:12)
      at MonitoredInstrumentation._rejectPendingCrashPromise (../node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/android/tools/MonitoredInstrumentation.js:56:37)
      at MonitoredInstrumentation._onInstrumentationTerminated (../node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/android/tools/MonitoredInstrumentation.js:51:10)
      at Instrumentation._onTerminated (../node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/android/tools/Instrumentation.js:52:18)

detox[13529] ERROR: [cli.js] Command failed: jest --config e2e/config.json --testNamePattern '^((?!:ios:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 e2e
```

having this configuration on my .detoxrc.json file

```
{  
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "devices": {
    "android.attached": {
            "type": "android.attached",
            "device": {
                "adbName": "278a2cdd6e1c7ece"
            }
        },
    "emulator": {
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_3"
      }
    },
    "simulator":{
    
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "device": {
          "type": "iPhone 12"
        }
  }
},
  "apps": {
    "android.debug": {
      "type": "android.apk",
      "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug/app-dev-debug.apk",
      "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug  -DtestBuildType=debug && cd .."
    },
    "android.release": {
      "type": "android.apk",
      "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk",
      "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release && cd .."
    },
    "ios.debug": {
      "type": "ios.app",
      "binaryPath": "ios/staging.app",
      "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/dailypso.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -scheme staging -derivedDataPath ios/build"
    },
    "ios.release": {
      "type": "ios.app",
      "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk",
      "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/detox_poc.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -scheme detox_poc -derivedDataPath ios/build"
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "android.attached":{
      "device":"android.attached",
      "app": "android.debug"
    },
    "Adebug": {
      "device": "emulator",
      "app": "android.debug"
    },
    "Arelease": {
      "device": "emulator",
      "app": "android.release"
    },
    "Idebug": {
      "device": "simulator",
      "app": "ios.debug"
    },
    "Irelease": {
      "device": "simulator",
      "app": "ios.release"
    }
  }
}
```

with these version of packages

> React Native :"0.63.4"
> jest: "^26.6.3"

wanting just to  start with simple code of test
e2e/.firstTest.e2e.js

```
describe('Example', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await device.launchApp();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('welcome'))).toBeVisible();
  });

});
```

and lastly this android/build.gradle configuration

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 18
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        kotlinVersion = '1.4.20'
        // firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4')
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

any Ideas???!

Comment: Any luck finding a solution for this?